# invalid_request on function with variable defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use [this node library](https://github.com/santi8ago8/MercadoLibreNode) to integrate mercadolibre in my app.
But I'm getting this error message:

```
null { message: 'The following parameters are required: client_id,client_secret,grant_type,code,redirect_uri,caller.admin. Empty parameter redirect_uri',
  error: 'invalid_request',
  status: 400,
  cause: [] }
```

This is my code:

```
exports.authorize = function(req, res, next) {

    var meli = require('mercadolibre');

    var meliObject = new meli.Meli(process.env.MERCADOLIBRE_CLIENT_ID, process.env.MERCADOLIBRE_SECRET);

    var code = req.query.code;
    console.log('code');
    console.log(code);

    redirect_uri = 'https://example.com/dashboard';

    meliObject.authorize(code, redirect_uri, 
        function(err, response){ 

            console.log(err, response);
            res.redirect('/dashboard');

        }) 


};
```

How can I fix this?